# Как правильно реализовать валидацию формы в Laravel 6 при её отправке средствами AJAX

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

Помогите понять последовательность валидации формы, при отправки формы через AJAX (laravel 6)

1. В AJAX данные из формы я беру при помощи  `$('#form').serialize()` и
   передаю их по action формы.
2. В контроллере принимаются эти данные и отправляются в валидатор

   `Validator::make($request->all(), [
       // правила
   ])->validate();`
3. Если проверки не проходят, то валидатор формирует JSON с ошибками и отправляет их обратно. Ошибки обрабатываются при помощи JS и выводятся.
4. Если ошибок нету, то как правильно осуществить редирект на начальную форму? Если бы это была обычная проверка, без AJAX, я бы прописал `return back()->with('message', 'Изменения сохранены.');` после валидации в контроллере. Как реализовать в JS код выше? (редирект на начальную и запись в сессию).
5. При отправке формы средствами AJAX происходит проверка CSRF?
6. Правильно ли всё реализуется, нужно ли ещё что то делать или какие
   то дополнительные проверки. Спасибо за разъяснение, хочется
   послушать мнение знающих людей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3. Если ошибок нету, то как правильно осуществить редирект на начальную форму? Если бы это была обычная проверка, без AJAX, я бы прописал return back()->with('message', 'Изменения сохранены.'); после валидации в контроллере. Как реализовать в JS код выше? (редирект на начальную и запись в сессию).

   - Именно так делаете перезагрузку страницы с помощи JS, записав текст об успешном завершение в сессию

PHP

```
$request->session()->flash('success', 'Изменения сохранены.');
return response()->json(['reload' => 'true']);
```

JS

```
if (response.data.type == 'reload') {
   location.reload(true);
}
```

4. При отправке формы средствами AJAX происходит проверка CSRF?

   - Да CSRF проверка При отправке через AJAX происходит.

Вставь в HTML

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="viju1hHCwy3IMpzCxCVwb5W3WM0coVPKFmzyjYml">
```

JS

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found!');
}
```